# Plugged HD power the wrong way, how to recover data?

Tags: hard-drive

A few years ago, I bought a kit to connect internal hard drives to computers via USB. Unfortunately, I plugged the power cable the wrong way and the circuit burnt and emanated smoke.
I just found back this hard drive and I would like to know what are the solutions to get back data ?
This is a *Maxtor Diamond Plus 9 80GB ATA/133 HD*.
I found on the web the same model of hard drive, if I buy one and I replace the electronic part of my hard drive with the new one, could it be working ?

Here is the photo of the electronic part :
[image]

I surrounded in red a part that seems to be damaged, also, if I was to replace the electronic parts, how would I plug it back to the parts the are surrounded in blue and green in the photo ? (because they are soldered)

Thank you.

Comment: +1 for courage and persistence. But be honest and be smart - if the data is really important, let somebody else fix this. You don't know how to solder, you connected that USB thing wrongly - this is not your talent.

Answer (score 3):

From the picture, it looks that the PCB is damaged. If you want to replace the PCB, you have to get the same PCB model that is have the same firmware in order to work, but this method is not always a good solution, thus, it might not get your hard drive to work, however, if swiping the PCB didn't solve the problem, then soldering the chips will not be enough since the ROM chip is burned out, and the ROM chip is important chip that has unique codes for the hard drive to be recognized in any operating system. Losing this unique codes will make the drive difficult to work under any OS. So again, if swiping PCB didn't work, and there is an absolutely important files that you need to recover, you have to send it to a specialist to recover the files, and mostly they will be able to recover the files using their tools, and there is a high chance they are going to tell you that the drive won't be usable any more.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to replace the PCB, you will have to get the *exact* same model.

- Part in green: are you sure it cannot be removed from the casing? In all HDDs I opened up, the connectors are connected to the PCB only, not to the casing.
- Part in blue: if you can't unplug it (it looks like a connector), make sure to solder it back in the exact same way and direction it was when you unsoldered it from the original PCB. It might be difficult to access it however, it looks like it's soldered to the back of the PCB, so you'll have to flip it around (make sure you don't damage the wires by doing so).
- Part in red: looks pretty badly burnt. But even if that's the only damage you can see on the PCB, does not mean it's the only damage at all. Often this kind of PCB is multi-layered, meaning there might internal copper "wires" that have been damaged.

If you wanna repair it yourself, I suggest you try to find an online tutorial, or even better, a [Repair Café](http://repaircafe.org/) close to where you live.

---

However, even that is not guaranteed to work, [as iSR5 pointed out in his answer](https://superuser.com/a/1101872/606417).